# Convert Decimal or Varchar into Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, casting, converters

I have 2 fields.

Birth= Datatype Decimal(12,4) & Date = Datatype Date

```
Birth         Date 
19650101   2015-07-09
```

how do i get a result that looks like this

i want the result to be like this

```
Birth             Date          
1965-01-01       2015-07-09
```

where the Birth is a Date datatype and not a decimal (12,4)

Comment: What date does `19650101` represent? Jan 1, 1965?  If so how do you get 13.7 years between the two?

Comment: My bad.. don´t mind the 13.7 ... i will leave that as blank

Comment: So `19650101` represents Jan 1, 1965?

Comment: if i can only get the decimal of the Birth field into Date then ithat would be greate because then i think i can get the Years out by my self

Comment: Why are you storing Birth as a decimal? It is a date! You should store data in the proper datatypes. Then this kind of stuff isn't an issue. You will have to first cast your decimal as a (var)char, then cast it to a date, then finally do do the date math.

Comment: i have changed my question.
and i do not store my birth as decimal the source system for some reason does that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert the number `19650101` to a date use

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(Birth AS VARCHAR(8)), 112)
```

To get the number of years (to one decimal) you could do:

```
ROUND(
    DATEDIFF(day,
         CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(Birth AS VARCHAR(8)), 112),
         [Date])/365.25
     ,1)
```

Which won't be exact but should be close enough to tenths of a year.

Comment: when i try to convert the Birth that has an datatype of decimal to varchar i get this error.

Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar.

Comment: Thats because you have to make the varchar 13 because your decimal is 12, 4

Comment: still the same error 
the datatype of the Birth field is Decimal(12,0) = Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @Nils Then you have one or more values that does not represent a valid date.

Comment: yes my bad. i hade 12 characters in the field.. now it workes

Comment: for  44119.5253587963 its failing:  Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @Tk1993 The answer only works for numbers that are equivalent to a date in the format YYYYMMDD - yours is not, so I wouldn't expect it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
-- Create demo data
CREATE TABLE #dates(birth int, date date)

INSERT INTO #dates(birth,date)
VALUES(19650101,N'2015-07-09')

-- Your work
SELECT CONVERT(date,CONVERT(nvarchar(max),birth),112) as birth, date, 
        DATEDIFF(year,
            CONVERT(date,CONVERT(nvarchar(max),birth),112),
            date
        ) as years
FROM #dates

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #dates
```

This depends on the exact format you provides (`19650101`).

Comment: i have change my question.

Comment: Be careful here. DATEDIFF counts the date thresholds that are crossed so your years are not going to be accurate. For example if you have a start date of 2014-12-31 and an end date of 2015-01-01 datediff will return 1 and it has only been a single day. Not saying this approach is wrong, just making sure the OP understands the nuances of datediff.

Comment: Your question is the same? By the way, Your format can still be used. Birth is in the format you desires. I know that this may be inaccurate on edge cases. Instead you can use days and calculate the days under recognition of shift-years.

Comment: i get this error from your answer to. 
 CONVERT(date,CONVERT(nvarchar(max),birth),112)
 = Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: I would never use `nvarchar()` max for this conversion.  To hold 8 digits, you just need `varchar(8)`.  But the idea is correct.

Comment: Well in the conversion it won't count in any way. I normally take bigger nvarchar values for the conversion instead of risking conversion errors due to too small values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this conversion.

```
cast(cast(FLOOR(birth) as CHAR(8)) as DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to round. Just convert your decimal value and put "-" like below : )

```
select left(birth,4) +'-' + 
substring(convert(nvarchar,birth),5,2)+'-'+ 
substring(convert(nvarchar,birth),7,2)
```